# Getting query params before Angular hash

Tags: angular, routes, discord

I'm trying to use an oAuth2 from Discord it asks for a uri when i passed `http://localhost:4200/#/login/discord` it redirects to `http://localhost:4200/?code=CODE#/login/discord`

But I have to use hash on my routing becouse I use my backend on the same domain.

Is there any way to get the query params from de redirect uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have your api access as ‘domain.com/api’. This is standard. And it will avoid the problems with putting a # in after the domain.

Comment: I use asp.net core as a backend the problem that he doesn't listen only in /api